# Visual Studio exited with code 1 post-build event explorer

Tags: visual-studio

I have a simple post-build event to open Explorer. However, when I include this line, I always get an error, "exited with code 1" but Exporer opens to the folder specified.

How can I do this without reciving the error?

E.g., add the following line to a post-build event:

```
explorer C:\\aa
```

Comment: Could you tag exactly the version of visual studio that is affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions.
I managed to solve it by changing to:

start "" C:\aa

Answer (score 1):

Add another line "exit /b 0". This will tell the command to exit with error code 0.